# Data Versioning with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got some tables that I want to version data for.  As far the design is concerned, these are insert only tables.  The tables are something like this

```
TABLENAME
----------
SURROGATE_KEY_ID
USER_VISIBLE_NATURAL_KEY_ID
VERSION
VALUE
```

What I want is for whenever I insert a record, the new record should have a version that is one bigger than the previous max version for a given USER_VISIBLE_NATURAL_KEY_ID set.  My desires for version is to be able to tell new data from old data, while retaining the old data.  You know, standard history tracking, audit kinda stuff.

I tried a trigger like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TABLENAME_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLENAME
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    LATEST VERSION NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(MAX(VERSION), 0) INTO LATEST_VERSION FROM TABLENAME
    WHERE TABLE_NAME.USER_VISIBLE_NATURAL_KEY_ID = :NEW.USER_VISIBLE_NATURAL_KEY_ID;
    :NEW.VERSION = LATEST_VERSION +1;
END;
```

This gives me a mutating table error, I assume because I'm trying to peek into TABLENAME to find the max(version) while inserting a new row.

How can I make this approach work, or if I'm totally wrong headed, what's a better approach?

Comment: How about an independent sequence to automatically populate the `VERSION` column?  The `VERSION` column will provide an ordering for a `USER_VISIBLE_NATURAL_KEY_ID` regardless of gaps. i.e. why does `VERSION` have to be the next value rather than simply a greater value?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. How would you suggest dealing with sequence roll over? Notice when it happens and archive old data before that?

Comment: If there is ever a concern about a rollover, I usually create a 2-part identifier based on date and sequence. Then order by the id, timestamp, seq. Set the date/timestamp to an appropriate granularity and there is no need to worry about sequence rollover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [Glenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726422/glenn) made an answer, I would accept it, but in lieu of that, I have elected to make a sequence to pull version from.  I have also created a view that abstracts version to be a sequential series starting at 1.

Something like

```
SELECT 
  id,
  user_visible_natural_key_id,
  (SELECT count(b.id) 
    FROM tablename b 
    WHERE b.id < a.id 
    AND b.database_created_datetime <= a.database_created_datetime 
    AND b.version < a.version 
    AND b.user_visible_natural_key_id = a.user_visible_natural_key_id ) + 1 
  AS version,
value,
database_created_datetime
FROM tablename a
```

which gives me something I can select version 1 or 2 from.

I'm not totally happy with my view yet, but I'll update this answer as I beat on it a little

Answer (score 1):

I would consider looking into Oracle's [Flashback Data Archive](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01011) functionality instead, available since Oracle version 11.

It would allow you to model your table very naturally (no need for a version column or a trigger), while easily adding very configurable change history tracking.  You can then use flashback queries to view past data. It's quite powerful.

Comment: One Note:
Flashback Data Archive requires Oracle EE. I strongly recomend this feature only since oracle 12c. I see huge amount of bugs and restrictions in 11g.

Comment: @Evgeniy: Thanks for the feedback. About the feature being available in EE only, I can't check it right now, but based on what I read, the feature should be available in all editions for free. Though it's true that in EE, you gain access to more advanced features. See the subtitle [Licensing Changes (All Database Versions for Free)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/flashback-data-archive-fda-enhancements-12cr1).

Comment: Seems you are right. I based my knowledge about licensing on this link https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#DBLIC109. In that article is written "Basic Flashback Data Archive is in all editions. Optimization for Flashback Data Archive requires EE and the Advanced Compression option" which I miss

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm on 11g for now. Should we upgrade, is flashback good in the situation where select statements usually want all the versions?

Comment: Unless auditing is central to what you need to do, I wouldn't upgrade just for that.  Why don't you setup a basic test/prototype with your current version, and see if it works for you?  My intent was just to suggest something built-in that may prevent you from having to reinvent the wheel.  But it'll really be up to you to try it out, and make sure it is flexible and stable enough for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having version number in your table can you try implementing effective from date and effective to date. While inserting a new version for a record update the *effective to date* of the old record to SYSDATE and for the new version update the *effective from date* as SYSDATE and *effective to date* as NULL. The record with a NULL effective to date is your latest record. In this approach you can also generate a version number (logical) using SQL queries (in case you want to show this version number somewhere on a report).

Due to some reason if you want to maintain version number in your table a sequence would be a better choice. Create a sequence for each such table and while inserting a new record use sequence.NEXTVAL in your insert statement itself. This way you will altogether avoid the overhead of the trigger. Though, in this case you will not be guaranteed of a gap free version (in case someone rolls back the transaction after the insert the sequence will produce gaps).

Comment: That's similar to something I have implemented that I'm not totally satisfied with.  I've got a"database_create_date" and a view that infers version by counting how many dates preceded that date. It only has millisecond resolution, do sometimes we get version number collision, which doesn't work for us.  How do effectivity dates deal with two simultaneous inserts(or updates)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer to the question *"How can I make this approach work?"*.
The main troublemaker is the condition *"whenever I insert a record, the new record should have a version that is one bigger than the previous max version"*. So we can't use sequences to effective deal with concurrency. Instead we had to request some kind of explicit lock (exclusive lock on first version of the object for example). Owner of the lock able to select max version of that object without risk to get not actual data. So you may use `select for update` + `insert` instead of `insert` + trigger for example. Or use package API for creating new versions of the object.

**Upd:** example for simple table `tab(id, val, ver)`

`select * from tab where id = :id and ver = 0 for update;`

`insert into tab(id, val, ver) values(:id, :new_val, (select max(ver) + 1 from tab where id = :id));`

Comment: Could you expand on select for update + insert?  I'm not sure I undertand